# A question about nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory

If G is a finite nilpotent group, then every minimal normal subgroup of $G$ is contained in the center of $G$ and has prime order.

Comment: Have you considered what $N\cap Z(G)$ might look like if $N$ were a minimal normal subgroup?

Comment: First, the minimal normal subgroup is a abelian p-group, consider the intersection of the minimal normal subgroup and the commutator subgroup of G is the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A finite nilpotent group is a product of $p$-groups. So you can do a very quick computation to show that you can reduce to the case where $G$ is a $p$-group.

Then look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/a-question-about-p-group/8400#8400) to answer Steve D's comment query.

Comment: Well, we can get by with more generality by considering that eventually [G,G,...,N] must be central, and contained in N. This shows the question is true even if we remove the word "finite".

Comment: @Steve D: Agreed.