# Every proper normal subgroup of a $p$-group contains non-trivial central elements

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

How do I prove the following statement?

> Let $G$ be a $p$-group, $H$ - its normal subgroup, $H\neq \{e\}$. Then the center of $G$
>   $$
> Z(G)=\{a\in G\ \ |\ \ \forall x\in G\ \ ax=xa\}
> $$
>   has non-trivial intersection with $H$, i.e. $H\cap Z(G) \neq \{e\}$.

As far as I understand, this is about finding central elements in a normal subgoup. Maybe there is some straightforward way to construct such an element (using inner automorphisms, for instance...)?

Comment: Are you missing some condition? The symmetric group $S_n$ for $n>2$ has trivial center, but non-trivial normal subgroup $A_n$.

Comment: @moonlight, yes, thank you, of course, it's a p-group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ act on $H$ by conjugation. As $H$ is a non-trivial p-group, then $\vert H\vert\equiv \mbox{fixed points} \mod p.$

This implies that $H\cap Z(G)$ has size divisible by p. Thus $H\cap Z(G)$ is nontrivial.

Comment: I assume that you are familiar with the class equation, anyway it's a duplicate of [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/a-normal-subgroup-intersects-the-center-of-the-p-group-nontrivially)

Comment: Oh, I got it, thank you! I wish you told that it's a duplicate earlier, we could just delete the whole thing...

Comment: @Glinka I saw it after I wrote the "answer"..sorry

Comment: How do you use the normality of H?