# Intersection of a normal subgroup with the centre of a $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

For homework, I'm asked to show that a normal subgroup of a $p$-group intersects the centre of the $p$-group nontrivially (*Herstein* section 2.12 P. 15).

This question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/a-normal-subgroup-intersects-the-center-of-the-p-group-nontrivially), but to prove it, I actually proved a stronger claim; that $N \cap Z(P) = Z(N)$. I'd like to know if this is right, and if so, if my proof is correct.

First, I show that if a subgroup of an arbitrary group is normal, then it's a union of conjugacy classes, i.e.
$$N = \left(\bigcup_{a \in N} C(a)\right) = Z(N) \sqcup \left(\bigcup_{a \in N\setminus Z(N)} C(a)\right).$$
Choosing representatives $a_1,\dots,a_r$ for each non-central conjugacy class, the class decomposition for $N$ reads
$$N = Z(N) \sqcup \left(\bigsqcup_{i=1}^r  C(a_i)\right).$$
Now let $P$ be a group of order $p^n$ for some $n > 0$, and let $N \trianglelefteq P$. As $P$ is a $p$-group, its centre $Z(P)$ is nontrivial.

Further, as $N \trianglelefteq P$, we write $N = \bigcup_{a\in N} C(a)$; choosing representatives $a_1,\dots,a_r$ for each conjugacy class that is not in the centre of $N$, we have that $$N = Z(N) \sqcup 
\left(\bigsqcup_{i=1}^r C(a_i)\right).$$

Writing $P$ as a union of nontrivial disjoint conjugacy classes, together with $Z(P)$, we have that
$$P = Z(P) \sqcup\left(\bigsqcup_{j=1}^s C(b_j)\right),$$
where $b_1,\cdots,b_s$ are representatives of distinct non-central conjugacy classes of $P$.
\ind 
For each noncentral conjugacy class $C(a_i) \subset N$, we have that $C(a_i) \in P \setminus Z(P)$, since $P\setminus Z(P)$ is the complete collection of non-central conjugacy classes; since $Z(N) = \bigsqcup_{z \in Z(N)} C(z)$ which is the collection of central (singleton) conjugacy classes in $N$, and since $Z(P)$ is the complete collection of all central conjugacy classes of $P$, it follows that $Z(N)$ must be contained in $Z(P)$. As $Z(N)$ is non-trivial (since $N$ is a $p$-group), we have that
\begin{align*}
Z(P) \cap N &= Z(P) \cap \left(Z(N) \sqcup \left(\bigsqcup_{i=1}^r C(a_i)\right)\right) \\
&= Z(P) \cap Z(N) \cup \left(Z(P) \cap \left(\bigsqcup_{i=1}^r C(a_i)\right)\right) \\
&= Z(N) \cup \varnothing = Z(N).
\end{align*}

Is this reasoning sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is false by counterexample; say, the normal subgroup $ C_4 $ of $ D_4 $ is abelian, but the center of $ D_4 $ is isomorphic to $ C_2 $. In your proof, I don't understand how you conclude from $ N - Z(N) \subset P - Z(P) $ that $ Z(N) \subset Z(P) $.

Comment: I see the error, thank you.