# Non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ intersects the center $Z(G)$ non-trivially

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I've seen a lot of information about this problem when $G$ is a $p$-group. But that need not be the case here.

> Let $G$ be a group such that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian. Let $H$ be a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$. Show $H\cap Z(G)$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $G$.

Clearly $H\cap Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$, but I am not sure how to show non-triviality. How does $G/Z(G)$ being abelian help us? Any hints?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/a-normal-subgroup-intersects-the-center-of-the-p-group-nontrivially) help? The result is true for any $p$-group, even those of nilpotency class greater than $2$.

Comment: If $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, then $G$ is nilpotent (of class at most $2$), and therefore $G$ is the product of its $p$-parts; $H$ is the product of *its* $p$-parts, and you can reduce the problem to the case of $p$-groups. At least in the finite case. Are you including the possibility that $G$ is infinite?

Comment: That is helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We must assume $G$ is nontrivial, of course, though the problem does not mention it (I guess it is implied by the existence of a nontrivial normal subgroup...).

If $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, then $G$ is nilpotent (of class at most $2$). If $G$ is finite, then it is the product of its $p$-parts, and the problem is reduced to the problem for $p$-groups, which is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/a-normal-subgroup-intersects-the-center-of-the-p-group-nontrivially) for nilpotent groups of any class.

But here’s an argument that does not require finiteness of $G$ or knowing about the nilpotency: note that because $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, then $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$.

Let $h\neq e$ be an element of $H$. If $h$ is central in $G$, there is nothing left to do. If $h$ is not central in $G$, let $g\in G$ be an element such that $gh\neq hg$. Then 
$$e\neq [h,g] = h^{-1}g^{-1}hg = h^{-1}(g^{-1}hg)\in H.$$
But we also have $[h,g]\in [G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$, thus exhibiting a non-trivial element of $H\cap Z(G)$.